# How to type hint function to be compatible with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, mypy, python-typing

Source code of `example.py`:

```py
from typing import Union, Any
import numpy as np

Number = Union[int, float, np.floating[Any]]


def add_one(num: Number) -> Number:
    return num + 1


inputs = [1, 2, 3]
outputs = [add_one(n) for n in inputs]

avg = np.mean(outputs)
```

Run mypy:

```
mypy example.py
src/example.py:14: error: Argument 1 to "mean" has incompatible type "List[Union[float, floating[Any]]]"; expected "Union[_SupportsArray[dtype[Any]], _NestedSequence[_SupportsArray[dtype[Any]]], bool, int, float, complex, str, bytes, _NestedSequence[Union[bool, int, float, complex, str, bytes]]]"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I can change everything to `np.floating[Any]` which fixes the numpy issue, but then I have to cast primitives to `np.float32(...)`:

```py
from typing import Any
import numpy as np


def add_one(num: np.floating[Any]) -> np.floating[Any]:
    return num + 1


inputs = [1, 2, 3]
outputs = [add_one(np.float32(n)) for n in inputs]

avg = np.mean(outputs)
```

Is there a correct way to type hint the `add_one` function so that its outputs are compatible with numpy functions such as `np.mean` **without breaking compatibility with the python primitive types**? The end goal is to be able to use it like this:

```py
inputs = [1, 2, 3]
outputs = [add_one(n) for n in inputs]
avg = np.mean(outputs)
```

Comment: Have a look at [numpy.typing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/typing.html#numpy.typing.ArrayLike) `ArrayLike` type.

Comment: @SUTerliakov I don't see how that might be helpful here. Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Just using `Number = Union[int, float]` doesn't throw any mypy error.